# Why stage duration and amount report comes with multiple zeros when export it

Tags: reporting, data-export

I am facing a very unusual problem. When I creates any report and add any number or currency field like stage duration, Age, Amount and export it in excel so all numbers fields come with additional unwanted zeros.
like if stage duration is 20 days so it's come as 20,000,000.

Kindly help how can I solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, Issue is solved just to change local setting. by clicking on Setup > Manage Users > Users > Edit Next to the Users Full name > Changed the locale > Save and exported the report and it was showing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Issue is solved just to change locale setting. by clicking on

Setup > Manage Users > Users > Edit Next to the Users Full name > Changed the locale > Save and exported the report and it was showing correctly.